# React JS Hooks with useState call same function but with params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm finding I'm having to duplicate the same function over again when I could write one function that handles different parameters. I can't get it to work so I wondered if someone could point me in the right direction? Below shows only 2 functions but in reality I've got many that all do the same thing.

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

const Section = ({ children }) => {
return (

    <>
        <Wrapper children = {children} />
    </>

   );
};
const HandlePages = () => {
    const [showPageFooDialogue, setShowPageFooDialogue] = useState(false);
    const [showPageBarDialogue, setShowPageBarDialogue] = useState(false);

    const [currentDialogue, setCurrentDialogue] = useState(0);


    {showPageFooDialogue && (
        <Section>

            <Headers heading = {"Foo Title"} currentDialogue = {currentDialogue} pages = {fooContents.length} />

            {fooContents[currentDialogue]}

        </Section>
    )}

        )


     {showPageBarDialogue && (
        <Section>

            <Headers heading = {"Bar Title"} currentDialogue = {currentDialogue} pages = {barContents.length} />

            {barContents[currentDialogue]}

        </Section>
    )}

    )
}

const fooContents = [

    //Lots of functionality specific to foo listed as the children of this function
];

const barContents = [

    //Lots of functionality specific to bar listed as the children of this function
];
return (

<button onClick={() => setShowPageFooDialogue(true)}>Click for Page Foo</button>
<button onClick={() => setShowPageBarDialogue(true)}>Click for Page Bar</button>

 )
}
export default HandlePages
```

Basically where I've got

```
    const [showPageFooDialogue, setShowPageFooDialogue] = useState(false);
    const [showPageBarDialogue, setShowPageBarDialogue] = useState(false);
```

I need just one function such as this but somehow pass 2 parameters to it:

```
  const [showPageGenericDialogue, setShowPageGenericDialogue] = useState(false);
```

and where I've got:

```
{showPageFooDialogue && (
        <Section>

            <Headers heading = {"Foo Title"} currentDialogue = {currentDialogue} pages = {fooContents.length} />

            {fooContents[currentDialogue]}

        </Section>
    )}

        )
{showPageBarDialogue && (
        <Section>

            <Headers heading = {"Bar Title"} currentDialogue = {currentDialogue} pages = {fooContents.length} />

            {barContents[currentDialogue]}

        </Section>
    )}

    )
}
```

I need just one function with 2 parameters for "Foo or Bar Title" (param1) and fooContents or barContents (param2):

```
{showPageGenericDialogue && (
        <Section>

            <Headers heading = {param1} currentDialogue = {currentDialogue} pages = {param2.length} />

            {param2[currentDialogue]}

        </Section>
    )}

    )
}
```

And then finally the buttons:

```
<button onClick={() => setShowPageFooDialogue(true)}>Click for Page Foo</button>
<button onClick={() => setShowPageBarDialogue(true)}>Click for Page Bar</button>
```

should just pass the parameters something like:

```
<button onClick={() => setShowPageGenericDialogue(true, fooParam1, fooParam2)}>Click for Page Foo</button>
<button onClick={() => setShowPageGenericDialogue(true, barParam1, barParam2)}>Click for Page Bar</button>
```

I've looked at various solutions but due to my limitations, I cannot apply them to this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reducer:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

It is a simple example, you can modify as per your needs.

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Or Take a look at `react-redux`.

**EDIT**

If you need functionality like you asked `one function with multiple parameter`

you can try to give a default state to your `useState` hook:

```
    const [myFooBar, setFoo] = useState(
        {
            'foo': false, 
            'bar': false
        }
    );
```

Changing the values:

```
setFoo(
  prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    'foo': true
  })
);
```

```
setFoo(
  prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    'bar': true
  })
);
```

Access it like this:

```
myFooBar.foo
myFooBar.bar
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that but as I mentioned previously I have tried a few solutions and I imagine they would work but due to my limitations I'm struggling to apply them to my project and looking at your example I am already having the same difficulty. Is there anyway you could elaborate on your answer specifically to my code? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the answer, please take a look.